# Why does Account Kit no longer send codes via SMS to my Android app?

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk, account-kit

I have an Android app with Account Kit based SMS verification. The app is not on the Play Store yet, as it is still in development. Previously we have managed to use Account Kit with no trouble at all. We have multiple developers working on the app who have had no issue with receiving Account Kit SMSes on the dev version of the app. We tend to re-install the app several times a week, which is why we go through the SMS verification flow quite regularly.

**However, one fine day, we stopped receiving SMS codes for Account Kit, across any device running the dev version of our app.**

Is it possible that we surpassed some quota? This is happening even when we run our app on devices with phone numbers we haven't used before. I could not find any documentation specifying a quota for dev version of apps...

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your app was caught by the abuse filters. If your logins to messages sent ratio is low, the app might get blacklisted by spam protection filters because most of the SMS messages being sent out did not result in a successful login.

Try going to the "Did not get a code" screen and select either receiving a phone call or getting a Facebook notification (if you have your number hooked up to your FB account) and see if the code arrives.

If not, you can also try taking your app out of "Dev mode" temporarily and see if it works.

If none of those works, contact Facebook's dev support with your app id to diagnose what's blocking you: https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/

(Please do not post your app id on message boards here)

Comment: We successfully received a code via phone call, which tells me the spam protection is not the issue. Also managed with Facebook notification. We've have Dev mode turned off in one of our apps, and we still see a problem.

Comment: @IsmailKhan are you able to solve this issue? We are also using facebook account is our application and many customers are reporting that sms are not received.

Comment: @hhsadiq , we switched to Firebase Phone Auth and have not had any trouble since. So no, didn’t solve it :(

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. Firebase Phone Auth works fine with ported numbers? One of our company's engineer says that firebase had some issues in delivering sms codes to ported numbers in Pakistan.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting an entire day on this, I stumbled upon the [Account Kit website](https://www.accountkit.com/) which has a passwordless authentication itself and allows users to login to the website using their phones.

I tried to log in using my phone. **And I still did not receive the confirmation SMS.**

I don't know what's wrong, but I don't think it has anything to do with your code.